# Distinct Count & Distinct Count with Condition in a Single Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subset, distinct

| Model ID | Work Order Number | Purchase Order Lines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | x | 5450 |
| 123 | x | 5400 |
| 123 | y | 5200 |
| 123 | y | 5500 |

I have something like the table above in my SQL Server database. I want a query to return the the distinct Model ID, count of distinct Work Orders, and distinct count of work orders where Purchase Order Lines are not 5450 or 5400.

From the table above the result of the query should be as follows:

| Model ID | Distinct Work Orders | Distinct Work Orders excluding PO lines 5400 and 5450 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 1 |

Is there a way to do this without using multiple sub queries or temporary tables?

Comment: Yes, use conditional aggregation.

Comment: can you show or share an example of this?

Comment: [Conditional aggregation sql server](https://www.google.com/search?q=Conditional+aggregation+sql+server)

Comment: What would the results be if the second row were 6400 instead of 5400?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COUNT DISTINCT with a case statement. Something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnName)
      , COUNT(DISTINCT ( CASE WHEN SomeCondition = True THEN ColumnName ELSE NULL END)) FilteredDistCount 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: `CASE` **expression**, not statement.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you, I have learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you might actually mean work orders that do not have 5400 or 5450, even if they have other values.

You can do this with a difference:

```
select count(distinct workorder),
       (count(distinct workorder) - 
        count(distinct case when purchaseorder not in (5400, 5450) then workorder end)
       )
from t;
```

Comment: Yes this would be very useful! However in my company's case if either 5400 or 5450 is used on a PO then other one could accompany it...but that is a very good observation that will be useful for me someday!

Comment: @Omar123456789 . . . The question is whether there are *any other* codes on the PO.